# Android. Подсчет одинаковых слов в JSON

Tags: android, json

На вход получаю такой JSON (пример):

```
"data1":[
{
"firstName":"John",
"lastName":"Doe"
}],
"data2":[
{
"firstName":"Anna",
"lastName":"Smith"
}],
"data3":[
{
"firstName":"Peter",
"lastName":"Doe"
}]
```

Нужно в listView "подсветить" одинаковые фамилии. Мне интересен сам алгоритм (теория). Всем спасибо.

Comment: преобразуй json в pojo с помощью gson. потом в адартере как-то находи одинаковые фамилии и сообщай вью холдеру, что вьюху надо "подсветить"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сначала удобнее всего десериализовать джейсон в список пользорвателей с полями, например, имя, фамилия, группа. потом пройтись по нему циклом, для каждого проверяя, одинакова ли фамилия с кем-нибудь из оставшихся. если нашлись совпадения, фиксируешь что они принадлежат одной группе(например интом для каждой группы). далее рендеришь в листвью и у нулевой, например, группы не подсвечиваешь фамилию, у остальных подсвечиваешь каждую группу разным цветом.

это самый простой вариант, если особо не задумываться о сложности и времени выполнения. если список огромный, возможно целесообразнее использовать какой-нибудь эффективный алгоритм сортировки, потом бежать по отсортированному списку и присваивать номер группы соседям с одинаковой фамилией

Answer (score 2):

1. json это всего лишь данные
2. *"подсветить" одинаковые фамилии* - это уже обработка данных

Вам нужно закрыть gap между п.1 и п.2 - для этого надо сначала json превратить в массив Java объектов и потом эти данные обработать. Способов превращения json в объекты масса, как указывали в каментах, православным в мире Java является Google Gson

После Gson вы получите что-то типа: `List<MyObject>`, где `MyObject` это Java класс, который описывает ваши объекты.

Далее в духе Java надо всю эту историю засунуть в адаптер `ListView`, далее можно (и нужно) использовать перегрузку метода адаптера `getItemViewType()`, чтобы отличать элементы сдвоенные и не сдвоенные (чтобы в `getView()` *подсвечивать* одинаковые фамилии)

В общем как то так